# How to extract src and dest ip and protocol type from wireshark k12 file using perl?

Tags: perl, ip, wireshark

Hey guys I'm trying to extract the source and destination ip and the protocol type from a wireshark capture that I have. Has to be a perl program that will print the source/destination/protocol type on screen.

Here's a snippet from the file

```
+---------+---------------+----------+
03:00:22,827,689   ETHER
|0   |01|00|5e|7f|ff|fa|c0|14|3d|5a|61|21|08|00|**45|00|00|7a|00|00|40|00|01|11|c7|44|c0|a8|01|8c|ef|ff|ff|fa**|e6|78|07|6c|00|66|13|60|4d|2d|53|45|41|52|43|48|20|2a|20|48|54|54|50|2f|31|2e|31|0d|0a|48|4f|53|54|3a|20|32|33|39|2e|32|35|35|2e|32|35|35|2e|32|35|30|3a|31|39|30|30|0d|0a|4d|41|4e|3a|20|22|73|73|64|70|3a|64|69|73|63|6f|76|65|72|22|0d|0a|4d|58|3a|20|33|0d|0a|53|54|3a|20|73|73|64|70|3a|61|6c|6c|0d|0a|0d|0a|
```

I know that the bolded is the source and destination ip and the |11| is the protocol type. Just not sure how to convert it/read it in then print it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with [Net::Sharktools](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSharktools)